# Is there any place you can safely skydive without a parachute?

Tags: friction, velocity

While trying to explain to someone how a kitten walked away from a fall from a skyscraper I got to wondering if there's any place a human could do that and I find myself out of my depth.

The only place that seems possible is Titan but I'm not sure.

My basic thoughts:

The gravity there is about 1/7th that of Earth.  My impression is that should reduce the terminal velocity accordingly.

Where I get stumped is dealing with Titan's atmosphere--it's not like Earth's (for which I'm stumped on figuring what will happen) and it's much colder (which I think will increase density and thus drag by the ratio of the absolute temperatures.)

Or is there any other place I've missed?

(Gas giants don't count as there's no surface to land on.)

Comment: Just to clarify - this is limited to the Solar System, right? (Otherwise it would certainly be too broad I think.)

Comment: Maybe the question could be rephrased to ask under what conditions, if any, a person would be able to do this.

Comment: Have I understood correctly, that a cat jumped from a skyscraper and wasn't injured? How is that?

Comment: @Eduardo :
Cats are light compared to their cross-section area. They reach a terminal velocity of about 100 km/h. Moreover, their tail acts as a gyroscope and they instinctively reposition themselves during the fall to land on their feet. That said, they have amazing absorbers in those legs. There's a story of a cat falling down a 19 story building that only lightly bruised its chest, which goes to show that their legs damp the hell out of the fall.

Comment: I don't know about the safety but it has been done on Earth http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRB-woVjlFY

Comment: This [What if?-article](http://what-if.xkcd.com/30/) explores the possibilities of airplane flight on different solar system bodies. The same parameters (strength of gravity and thickness of atmosphere) are of importance for this as for the terminal velocity. It seems like Titan is your best bet. The atmosphere is four times thicker than on Earth.

Comment: @ChrisWhite What other bodies do we have enough data on to possibly know whether it could be done?

Comment: @EduardoGuerrasValera It was a kitten--smaller than a cat and thus it's terminal velocity was lower.  It was obviously hurting a bit but walking under it's own power.  It also wasn't an intentional flight, the kitten went after a caged bird and ended up going off the balcony instead.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Well, we're starting to build better models of [exoplanets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasolar_planet), especially the ones for which we know the mass, radius, *and* distance from the star.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yeah, but those models don't have atmospheric density.

Comment: I'm not really answering my own question, just pointing to the answer someone posted on another thread: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30157/

Comment: I think some Jackass videos can be quite educative about human resistance to falling on hard ground.

Comment: Speaking of hard ground, I think that the material you will be plunging into from your hypothetical fall should be taken into account. You can fall from a tall building into one of those matresses firefighters use for such occasions. There is a limit to how big a fall it will save you from, but I believe this increases your safe height threshold by a few hundred meters. The Mythbusters also made some experimenting on that, by having buster fall from different heights on water and concrete for comparison.